# Positioning Calendar

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar

How do you position the calendar to float in the page like the demo?

The example provided fixes the calendar at the upper left point.. fixed.  The code

```
<style>
  html, body {
    overflow: hidden; /* don't do scrollbars */
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar-container {
    width: 700px;
      position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .fc-header-toolbar {
    /*
    the calendar will be butting up against the edges,
    but let's scoot in the header's buttons
    */
    padding-top: 1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
  }
    .td_Info{
         width: 300px; 
    }
    .td_calendar{
         width: 700px; 
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>My Page</h1>
</div><br/>
<table><tr>
        <td class="td_Info">INFO<br>
          more<br> 
          more <br>
          more <br>
          more<br></td>
        <td class="td_cal"><div style="max-width: 500px;">
          <div id='calendar-container'>
            <div id='calendar'></div>
          </div>
        </td></tr>
       </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Renders
[Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oowec.png)

I get that it is because of the fixed position on the style .. but when I take it off and put something like relative.. the calendar no longer renders properly..

[calendar render 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PDXN.png)

Comment: "like the demo"...there are lots of demos of fullCalendar. Which one do you mean? Anyway you can probably just examine the HTML source code of that page to see how they did it - the View Source or Developer Tools feature in any browser can help you. Also it's probably just some generic HTML and CSS to create a container which is centred in the page. Nothing to do with fullCalendar specifically.

Comment: I tried that, but the demo seems to be setup in a special case..  and when I say "Demo" I'm speaking of the page that is presented from Fullcalendar demos.   See: https://fullcalendar.io/#demos

Comment: If you open View Source on that page you'll see it's wrapped in some divs which control the page layout (they must have some CSS rules attached to them which help with positioning - you can see what those are by following the links to the CSS files loaded into the page, and/or by using your browser's element inspector to see what rules are applied to each element.

Comment: The only thing which is a "special case" about it is that the actual calendar display is loaded via Javascript based on which option is selected on the left-side menu. The calendar is always loaded into the `<div class='demos__main-container' id='demo-content'>` element (using the browser's element inspector shows you this fact). But that's not relevant to the overall layout or positioning of that element within the page, which is totally static.